# Find set of all parents in chain for multiple tips in an SQL nested set heirarchy

Tags: mysql, sql, tree-traversal, nested-sets

I have a large bifurcating hierarchy of 4 million nodes (2 million tips), organised as a nested set in an mySQL table (i.e. with rgt and lft positions defined for each node). I want an efficient way to take (say 1000) tip nodes, and find the set of all parent nodes that are passed through when traversing from these tips to the root of the hierarchy.

Is there an efficient SQL query I can use to get such a list?

Note that many of the higher level nodes will be passed through multiple times from different tips - I only need the set of all the unique parent nodes - duplicates can be thrown out.

Comment: I don't think you can get much better than the trivial solution of finding all parents of your nodes and use distinct. Is it too slow? Exceptions might exists for special cases: in a full and fully balanced binary tree, you would not need to actually traverse the tree, as the parent ids are known by looking at the node ids (but you would not use a nested set then). Or if you have a very deep tree and test e.g. 2 siblings with the same 1 million parents, some recursive cte might catch the 2nd one; but this additional effort will make your query slower in all other non-special cases.

Comment: Actually, I've just realised that it's easy to get all the parents for a tip in the nested set notation: it's just `SELECT id FROM t WHERE tip1 BETWEEN lft AND rgt`. But for 1000 tips I'll need to chain 1000 `BETWEEN` statements with `OR` conditions: (tip1 BETWEEN lft AND rgt) OR (tip2 BETWEEN lft AND rgt) OR (tip3 BETWEEN lft AND rgt) ... OR (tip1000 BETWEEN lft AND rgt). Is there a neat way to construct such a query?